# 8086 assembly - divide overflow

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I try to make a simple division in assembly but I get "Divide overflow" error.

My simple code:
cs:sum and cs:num is a byte variable. (db)

```
    mov ax, word ptr cs:sum
mov cl, 10
xor dx,dx
div cl ; divide by 10
mov cs:num, ah ; ger rightest
```

Not sure why - but as I say - I fail to devide properly.

So do you know what is that problem and how to solve it? thanks !

(I'm using cs deference because that's a TSR program)

Comment: A TSR ? Are you working on something for a museum exhibit ?

Comment: I'm not using assembly at all. I'm preparing to exam..=\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this to cause a division exception

```
mov ax, word ptr cs:sum
mov cl, 10
div cl
```

the value in `ax` (coming from `word ptr cs:sum`) must be >= 2560.

Either `word ptr cs:sum` isn't < 2560 or addressing is broken in your code and you're not storing the value in `word ptr cs:sum` or fetching it from there (e.g. you're not using the same segment value when referring to `sum`).

Those are the only possibilities.

Comment: I already solve it. because your answer is the best - I'll sing this answer as accepted. thank you. BTW - C FTW!!