# Division of high numbers in assembly

Tags: optimization, assembly, x86

I tried to find a location of a crusor with an array of 1896(becomes the whole console in 2D, 79*24). For this I took the location and divided it by 79.

```
MOV AX, [Y-16H]
 DEC AX
 MOV BX, 79
 DIV BX   
 MOV Z, DL
 ADD Z, DH
 MOV DL, Z
 MOV Z, AL
 ADD Z, AH
 MOV DH, Z
```

I get an overflow error. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong please? maybe suggest a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [8086 assembly - divide overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149560/8086-assembly-divide-overflow)

Comment: @JensBjörnhager The other question is only superficially related.  The underlying cause of the divide-overflow is different in that question.  Accordingly, the knowledge provided in the answers is different as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`DIV BX` divides the 32-bit number formed by `DX` (high word) and `AX` (low word) by `BX`. You therefore need to clear `DX` (e.g. `XOR DX,DX`) prior to the division to avoid an overflow.

By the way, are you sure you don't want to divide by 80? I've never heard of a 79-column console, although I'm no expert on such matters

Comment: Define "doesn't work". I've tested it myself with the change I proposed, and there was no division overflow.

Answer (score 2):

As Michael mentioned, you need to clear the DX register prior to division.

That said, if you are interested in speed (the usual reason for assembly coding), it is *much* faster to transform the division by 79 into an equivalent operation using a multiplication and a right shift: `(x * 53093) >> 22`.

This works because `1/79th` is approximately equal to `53093 / (2**22)`.